# Swift 2: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Compilation error:Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "", size: 15)
    ]
```

Comment: `UIFont(name: size:)` returns an Optional which must be unwrapped.  In this case it would crash if you simply added `!` because `""` isn't a valid font name, but if your provide a real font name then `!` works.

Comment: Perfect it worked 
Thanks

Comment: @AymanIbrahim [NSObject:AnyObject]? You should change it to [String:AnyObject]?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really reproduce your issue since your code firstly does not compile for other reasons - fixing those just fixes everything :P

```
let navBarAttributesDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]? = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)!
]
```

So far for the issues with only the posted snippet.

*Note* as @LeoDabus mentioned: If you want to assign that dictionary as textAttributes to some attributed text you have to change its type to `[String: AnyObject]?`.

```
let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)!
]
```

Comment: [NSObject:AnyObject]? You should change it to [String:AnyObject]?or just ommit it

Comment: @LeoDabus Hmmm, I though of something like that but Xcode for some reason does not complain, it works fine both in playground and in a regular swift-file - I am confused

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes

Comment: @LeoDabus I see, it was not strictly an issue with the posted code alone with the context the code is probably used in - got it.